# Kernel of a natural map is a direct summand of the covariant extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I am reading chapter 2 of 'Homological Algebra' by Cartan and Eilenberg.

1/ Given a ring homomorphism $\varphi: \Lambda \rightarrow \Gamma$ and a right $\Gamma$-module $A$, we can treat $A$ and $\Gamma$ as $\Lambda$-modules, with the action of $\Lambda$ defined naturally through $\varphi$, and define the covariant $\varphi$-extension of $A$ as $A_\varphi =A\otimes_\Lambda \Gamma$.  The authors then

> define a $\Lambda$-homomorphism $A\rightarrow A_\varphi$ as
>   $A\otimes\varphi :A\otimes_\Lambda \Lambda \rightarrow A\otimes_\Lambda \Gamma$.

Is the above map specified by $A\otimes\varphi(a\otimes\lambda)=a\otimes \varphi(\lambda)$?

Am I correct to interpret the precise mapping here is the restriction of the map $A\otimes\varphi :A\otimes_\Lambda \Lambda \rightarrow A\otimes_\Lambda \Gamma$ to $A\otimes_\Lambda 1_\Lambda$?

2/ The authors also define a $\Gamma$-homomorphism $g:A_{(\varphi)}\rightarrow A$ by $g(a\otimes \gamma)=a\gamma$. Then

> the composition $A\rightarrow A_\varphi \rightarrow A$ is the
>   identity, which proves that $g$ is an epimorphism and Ker$(g)$ is a
>   direct summand as a $\Lambda$-module.

It is not clear to me why we can conclude Ker$(g)$ is a direct summand as a $\Lambda$-module

> If $A$ is $\Gamma$-projective then Ker$(g)$ is a direct summand as a
>   $\Gamma$-module.

I also don't see why.

I guess these facts are easy to see, and the reason why I do not is I have little background in module theory (I just update my module theory background as I read homological algebra). If that is the case, please help by just stating the relevant theorems/propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right.
2. If $M'\stackrel f→M\stackrel g→M'$ are morphisms such that $g∘f$ is the identity, then $\ker g⊕\operatorname{Im}f=M$.

If $A$ is $\Gamma$-projective, then use the short exact sequence of $Γ$-modules: $0→\ker g→A_{(φ)}→A→0$.